# Tkinter RSS Ticker accelerating at every update

Tags: python, tkinter, scroll, rss, updating

There's no help on google, I've asked some people as well but none of them seem to know how to answer my question.

I'm programming a GUI for a project, and it contains an RSS-Feed ticker.
It scrolls through the news and when it updates (every 3 seconds for obvious debug reasons) it speeds up a bit.
This means, if I run the program, after two hours the ticker is scrolling at a non-human readable speed.

The main code wasn't written by me, I modified it and added the update function.

```
main():

import tkinter as tk
from Press import RSSTicker

def displayRSSticker(win):
    # Place RSSTicker portlet
    tickerHandle = RSSTicker(win, bg='black', fg='white', highlightthickness=0, font=("avenir", 30))
    tickerHandle.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', anchor='se')

def main():
    # Set the screen definition, root window initialization
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.configure(background='black')
    width, height = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width, height))
    label = tk.Label(root, text="Monitor Dashboard", bg='black', fg='red')
    label.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', anchor='se')

    # Display portlet
    displayRSSticker(root)
    # Loop the GUI manager
    root.mainloop(0)

###############################
#     MAIN SCRIPT BODY PART   #
###############################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

RSSTicker class:

```
import feedparser
import tkinter as tk

class RSSTicker(tk.Text):
    # Class constructor
    def __init__(self, parent, **params):
        super().__init__(parent, height=1, wrap="none", state='disabled', **params)
        self.newsFeed = feedparser.parse('http://www.repubblica.it/rss/homepage/rss2.0.xml')
        self.update()

    # Class methods
    def update(self):
        self.headlineIndex = 0
        self.text = ''
        self.pos = 0
        self.after_idle(self.updateHeadline)
        self.after_idle(self.scroll)
        self.after(4000, self.update)

    def updateHeadline(self):
        try:
            self.text += '       ' + self.newsFeed['entries'][self.headlineIndex]['title']
        except IndexError:
            self.headlineIndex = 0
            self.text = self.feed['entries'][self.headlineIndex]['title']

        self.headlineIndex += 1
        self.after(5000, self.updateHeadline)

    def scroll(self):
        self.config(state='normal')
        if self.pos < len(self.text):
            self.insert('end', self.text[self.pos])
        self.pos += 1
        self.see('end')
        self.config(state='disabled')
        self.after(180, self.scroll)
```

I thought the problem lied in the `self.pos` variable, printing it out resulted in it counting up, resetting to 1 and counting up faster.. But it doesn't seem to be problem causing the acceleration of the ticker.
From what I've understood tho, the problem must be in the scroll method.

If someone understand how to keep the original scroll speed when updated, thank you.

Comment: It does look like your issue is a combination of the `update` and `scroll` methods. `scroll` calls itself ever 0.18 seconds however ever 4 seconds `update` calls scroll again and therefor starts a new loop that calls `scroll` every 0.18 seconds. So every time `update` loops you get a new instance of `after()` calling scroll ever o.18 seconds. To correct this you can add an identifier either passed to scroll or as a class attribute to let `scroll` know it has already started its loop and to not add more loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a couple tracking variables to make sure that `update` only starts the loop once and then next time `update` is called it will just run `scroll` without starting a new loop. At the same time if `scroll` is not called by `update` then it will continue looping as needed.

Change your `RSSTicker` class to the following:

```
class RSSTicker(tk.Text):
    # Class constructor
    def __init__(self, parent, **params):
        self.scroll_started = False # Tracker for first update.
        super().__init__(parent, height=1, wrap="none", state='disabled', **params)
        self.newsFeed = feedparser.parse('http://www.repubblica.it/rss/homepage/rss2.0.xml')
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.headlineIndex = 0
        self.text = ''
        self.pos = 0
        self.after_idle(self.updateHeadline)
        self.after_idle(lambda: self.scroll('update'))
        self.after(4000, self.update)

    def updateHeadline(self):
        try:
            self.text += '       ' + self.newsFeed['entries'][self.headlineIndex]['title']
        except IndexError:
            self.headlineIndex = 0
            self.text = self.feed['entries'][self.headlineIndex]['title']

        self.headlineIndex += 1
        self.after(5000, self.updateHeadline)

    def scroll(self, from_after_or_update = 'after'):
        self.config(state='normal')
        if self.pos < len(self.text):
            self.insert('end', self.text[self.pos])
        self.pos += 1
        self.see('end')
        self.config(state='disabled')
        # Check if the loop started by after.
        if from_after_or_update != 'update':
            self.scroll_started = True
            self.after(180, self.scroll)
        # If not started by after check to see if it is the 1st time loop is started by "update".
        elif self.scroll_started is False and from_after_or_update == 'update':
            self.scroll_started = True
            self.after(180, self.scroll)
        # If neither of the above conditions then do not start loop to prevent multiple loops.
        else:
            print("ran scroll method without adding new after loop!")
```

Comment: I'll test this tomorrow, thank you. By the way, Press is just the filename where the rss ticker class is. Sorry I didn't think about that.

Comment: @ShadeReogen Oh that's fine. Just the same this update to your class should fix your issue.

Comment: I just tried this and it gets me this error: TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: @ShadeReogen sorry updated now. I forgot to change the call to scroll to include the argument normally instead of how after uses it. If the code still has the same error then try this instead. `self.after_idle(lambda e: self.scroll('update'))`.